# Are admissions offers sent after the April 15 deadline?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, united-states

Do Universities in the US send admission offers after 15th April? If so, how many offers do they make?

Comment: On the one hand, I see how this is too specific due to the "If so, how many offers do they make bit" But on the other hand, if the question is understood as "is there a strict deadline of April 15th after which US Universities no longer send admission offers at all?" then the answer is **no**. The answer below seems to answer that question which PhD applicants might conceivably ask and which is not specific in the problematic way.

Comment: I don't understand how this can be considered off-topic. As Pete's answer indicates it's clearly answerable, I can see how it could be widely useful to a variety of people seeking graduate admissions (if a person hasn't received an offer by April 15th but hasn't gotten a rejection, does that mean it's game over for that admission season?). The OP didn't ask for a specific university, or something that only applies to them specifically. "How many offers" may be a bit too specific, but that seems a minor quibble which is easily fixed or addressed in an answer. Voting to re-open.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Yes, sometimes.**

(I am the Graduate Coordinator of the UGA math department, i.e., the faculty member who is most directly in charge of graduate admissions here.)  April 15th is "the singularity" for sure: we make offers months before, many of which are held until the weeks, days or hours before April 15th.  As the deadline approaches, we try to check back in with people and try to hear sooner rather than later if they will decline.

While we try our best to get everything resolved by April 15th, it is likely that we will not entirely succeed.  E.g. for us this year we made an offer that was received (just) after April 15th.  Things tend to move very quickly after April 15th as well: we can really burn through a waiting list when it turns out that a lot of people on it took *something* by the April 15th deadline.

If you are still interested in a department and haven't been rejected yet by them, I would say that today is a great today to write back and let them know you're still interested.  At this time of year, knowing that an offer is likely to be accepted is worth something to us.

Good luck.

Comment: should I send an email to the department coordinator or some professor?